# Can we get Answer numbers reverse in the user profile

Tags: discussion, bug, feature-request

The contrast for the *numbers* on selected answers is too low in the user profile. I have difficulty reading them.

To be clear, I *can* read them.. but it takes far more effort than it should. Merely reversing the numbers would help.

[image]

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately, this is something only SE the company can do. I added the [bug] tag, that should awaken the correct sleeping giants.

Comment: Thanks @PieBie -- I was going t post on meta but comments there in the past have eluded to posting at *specific* stacks if an issue is related to that stack... and apparently tags make things happen. I thought it was the feature request.. didn't even consider "bug" `:)` thanks for adding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note.. at some point this **was** implemented. I don't know when.. but they are reversed now.